# Leer json desde url con angular y mostrarlo en una tabla

Tags: angular, typescript

Tengo un formulario con dos inputs para introducir latitud y longitud. La idea es leer un archivo json desde una url, https://demo3654022.mockable.io/datos y comparar los datos introducidos con los del archivo json, si la latitud y la longitud son iguales, mostrar todos los datos en una tabla, he leído algo sobre NgIf y NgFor. Soy novato con angular y tampoco se si el código publicado esta bien.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

**Codigo app.component.ts:**

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { FormBuilder, FormGroup, Validators } from '@angular/forms';
import { MyserviceService } from './myservice.service';
import { HttpClient } from '@angular/common/http';

@Component({
    selector: 'app-root',
    templateUrl: './app.component.html',
    styleUrls: ['./app.component.css']
})

export class AppComponent implements OnInit {

    coordenadas: FormGroup;
    submitted = false;
    titulo = 'Tiempo estaciones meteorológicas';
    data = [];

constructor(private formBuilder: FormBuilder, private service: MyserviceService ) { }

    ngOnInit() {
       this.coordenadas = this.formBuilder.group({
       latitud: ['', Validators.required],            
       longitud: ['', [Validators.required]],
    });

       this.service.getJSON().subscribe(data => {
       console.log(data);
    });
  }

  onSubmit() {
     this.submitted = true;

     if (this.coordenadas.invalid) {
         return;
     }
     alert("Coordenadas enviadas");
    }
 }
```

**Codigo app.module.ts:**

```
import { BrowserModule } from '@angular/platform-browser';
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { AppRoutingModule } from './app-routing.module';
import { AppComponent } from './app.component';
//import { HttpClient } from '@angular/common/http';
import { ReactiveFormsModule, FormsModule } from '@angular/forms';

@NgModule({
  declarations: [
   AppComponent
 ],
 imports: [
   BrowserModule,
   AppRoutingModule,
   FormsModule,
   ReactiveFormsModule, 
   //HttpClient
 ],
 providers: [],
 bootstrap: [AppComponent]
})
export class AppModule { }
```

**Codigo myservice.service.ts:**

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { HttpClient } from '@angular/common/http';
import { Observable } from 'rxjs';

@Injectable({
 providedIn: 'root'
})

export class MyserviceService {

   baseURL:string = "https://demo3654022.mockable.io/datos";

   public getJSON(): Observable<any> {
     return this.http.get(this.baseURL);
   }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Es muy sencillo mostrar los datos. Puedes hacer algo así:

```html
  <span class='col-12' *ngIf="datosCargados"  >

    <table  class='table' >
      <thead>
        <th>id</th>
        <th>ubicacion</th>
        <th>latitud</th>
        <th>longitud</th>
        <th>temperaturamin</th>
        <th>temperaturamax</th>
      </thead>
      <tbody>
        <tr *ngFor="let datos of datosCargados">
          <td>{{datos.id}}</td>
          <td>{{datos.ubicacion}}</td>
          <td>{{datos.latitud}}</td>
          <td>{{datos.longitud}}</td>
          <td>{{datos.temperaturamin}}</td>
          <td>{{datos.temperaturamax}}</td>
        </tr>
      </tbody>

    </table>
  </span>

  <div class='col-12'>

  <h1 *ngIf="!datosCargados"  >No hay datos cargados</h1>
  </div>
```

Toma en cuenta que modifique el mock para para que mostrara esta estructura:

```
{ 
   "resultados":[ 
      { 
         "id":1,
         "ubicacion":"badajoz",
         "latitud":"38° 52' 43'' N",
         "longitud":"6° 58' 15'' O",
         "temperaturamin":14,
         "temperaturamax":29
      },
      { 
         "id":2,
         "ubicacion":"otro",
         "latitud":"38° 21' 43'' N",
         "longitud":"6° 41' 15'' O",
         "temperaturamin":14,
         "temperaturamax":29
      },
      { 
         "id":2,
         "ubicacion":"otro mas",
         "latitud":"38° 21' 45'' N",
         "longitud":"6° 12' 15'' O",
         "temperaturamin":14,
         "temperaturamax":29
      }
   ]
}
```

Lo hice así para que fueran varios resultados y poder trabajar con ello.

En lo personal yo filtraría en la `API` para no traer todos los datos pero si lo quieres filtrar en tu componente puedes hacerlo dentro del servicio. Te dejo un ejemplo funcionando [aqui](https://stackblitz.com/edit/consumir-api)

> OJO.. El mock caduca en 24 horas. Para que hagas otro si lo necesitas.

Comment: Buenas Angel, he tratado de replicar lo mismo que tienes tu y a partir de ahi empezar a trabajar, pero copio tal cual lo tienes en  https://stackblitz.com/edit/consumir-api y no me visualiza nada.

Comment: Revisa los imports de `app.module` y si te esta tirando la consola algún error publicalo en tu pregunta. La pregunta tiene un link que dice editar en la parte de abajo.

Comment: Ya lo arreglé, era un fallo tonto, gracias por tu ayuda.

Comment: @dreamy jajaja, te entiendo. Pero uno comienza aceptar esos fallos despues de los 30! jajaja XP (tengo un montón de esos todavía XS)